# <input type="number"> en Genexus

Tags: genexus

¿Cómo se puede lograr que una variable de entrada numerica en Genexus, tenga los botones para aumentar o disminuir el valor?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Esa forma de ver el numerico se hace con un type específico de HTML que genexus no genera de esa forma. Si quisieras hacer eso hoy, las posibilidades que veo son:

1. User Control
2. Usar botones (programando el comportamiento vos), y darle otra estética al campo, no te va a quedar igual.